Нужна ли запятaя
"Пусть я никогда его не любила(,) и не полюблю, но он хороший".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли запятая на месте пропуска? Можно ли назвать часть предложения "и не полюблю" присоединительным членом или это просто однородные сказуемые?

Правильно:
Пусть я никогда его не любила и не полюблю, но он хороший.
Пояснение

Можно ли считать союз И присоединительным? Обычно такой вопрос возникает, когда однородные сказуемые значительно распространены и по семантике отдалены друг от друга, но даже в этом случае постановка запятой будет всего лишь авторской пунктуацией.

В данном же случае нет оснований и для авторской запятой, а разная грамматическая форма не влияет на однородность сказуемых. К тому же интонационно они произносятся без паузы.

Но если автору нужно обозначить присоединительный характер второго сказуемого, то нужно использовать другой союз:

Пусть я никогда его не любила, да и не полюблю, но он хороший.

В данном случае запятая не нужна, т.к. это  однородные сказуемые, связанные одиночным соединительным союзам и.  Производитель действия один.
